# Uploading a .dat file into R to use the lme() function, having trouble

Tags: r, dataframe, lme4, multilevel-analysis

I uploaded a .dat file in R to perform some multilevel modeling on it. It allows me to check the dimension

```
dim(lang.IQ.data.set)
[1] 3758   11
```

I ran the `library(nlme)` to run the package to use the `lme()`

I then tried to run my null model

```
null=lme(fixed = langPOST~1 , random = 1|schoolnr, data=lang.IQ.data.set)
```

I keep getting this error message for my code

```
Error in reStruct(random, REML = REML, data = NULL) : 
  object 'schoolnr' not found
```

I then ran `data(lang.IQ.data.set)`

and got the error message

```
Warning message:
In data(lang.IQ.data.set) : data set ‘lang.IQ.data.set’ not found
```

It appears my .dat file has not been put in? even though it shows up as being imported in R studio? Since it also cannot find the column in the data set "schoolnr"

Hope this makes since, thanks. I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data()` is a command for loading data from packages---and is rarely needed at all. You have already loaded data from a file, and by `dim(lang.IQ.data.set)` giving the dimensions of it, evidently it worked--at least somewhat. The issue seems to be that is doesn't have a column named `schoolnr`. (Your error says "`schoolnr` not found", "`lang.IQ.data.set` not found".) Look at `names(lang.IQ.data.set)` to see the column names of your loaded data.

Additionally, you have a syntax error. Random effects need to start with a `~` so R knows it's a formula. Use `random = ~ 1|schoolnr` in your call.

Comment: Thank you. So I ran names() and its gave me back for the first column "schoolnr" that I used in the lme() function. Im not sure why its saying it cannot find it.

Comment: @ts3n_mt Oops -  just noticed your syntax error. Random effects need to start with a `~` so R knows it's a formula. Use `random = ~ 1|schoolnr` in your call.

Comment: Yes the syntax error cleared it up! Appreciate the help.